# combine two before insert on triggers mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a pair of triggers on one table that concat 3 columns into one.  I need to do this same thing with different formatting into another column.  Mysql tells me i cant have the same trigger at the same time.  Is there a way to combine the two sets of triggers so that they are each calling two things? I have looked for this and cant seem to find an answer or figure it out.  Just adding the SET call into it throws the error.  Thanks
Here are the current working triggers if they are seperated.

Set 1

```
CREATE TRIGGER combinedDescNameinsert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON  markers
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.combinedDescName = CONCAT(new.descName, '-', new.DoorGroupID, '-', new.DoorID);

CREATE TRIGGER combinedDescNameupdate_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON  markers
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.combinedDescName = CONCAT(new.descName, '-', new.DoorGroupID, '-', new.DoorID);
```

Set 2

```
 CREATE TRIGGER combinedDoorNameinsert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON  markers
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.combinedDoorName = CONCAT(new.descName, ' - DoorGroupID: ', new.DoorGroupID, ' - DoorID: ', new.DoorID);

CREATE TRIGGER combinedDoorNameupdate_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON  markers
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.combinedDoorName = CONCAT(new.descName, ' - DoorGroupID: ', new.DoorGroupID, ' - DoorID: ', new.DoorID);
```

Comment: can't you just do `set doorname = ..., descname=...`? you're not limited to changing just one field in the record.

Comment: Use `BEGIN` and `END` for trigger bodies with more than one statement.

Comment: man - im not sure why i spaced on the just adding another one - thanks alot Marc B

Answer (score 0):

Just like, IF...THEN, LOOP, stored procedures, etc... triggers with multiple statements must enclose them in `BEGIN...END`. Since such statements need terminated themselves, the delimiter must be temporarily changed to differential between body statements' ends and the end of the trigger itself.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER combinedDescNameinsert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON  markers
BEGIN
FOR EACH ROW
   SET new.combinedDescName = CONCAT(new.descName, '-', new.DoorGroupID, '-', new.DoorID);
   SET new.combinedDoorName = CONCAT(new.descName, ' - DoorGroupID: ', new.DoorGroupID, ' - DoorID: ', new.DoorID);
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER combinedDescNameupdate_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON  markers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.combinedDescName = CONCAT(new.descName, '-', new.DoorGroupID, '-', new.DoorID);
   SET new.combinedDoorName = CONCAT(new.descName, ' - DoorGroupID: ', new.DoorGroupID, ' - DoorID: ', new.DoorID);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```